# Geometry question involving triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

**Question**:

> $ABC$ is a right angle triangle at $A$. $AD$ is the altitude through A; E is a point on AC such that $AE=CD$. F is a poibnt on AB such that $AF=BD$. Prove that $BE=CF$.
>
> *[Challenge And Thrill Of Pre-College Mathematics - Exercise 3.5](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=SnvBeodeTDcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=challenge%20and%20thrill%20of%20precollege%20mathematics&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Xj93VM2vHIunuQTO0oCQBg&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)*

**My attempt**:

I prepared this diagram:

[image]

on GeoGebra. Even after trying a lot, I can't progress at all in this question. Can someone please help me out with some hints or anything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's enough to show that
$$|BD|^2 + |AC|^2 \stackrel{\color{red}{?}}{=} |CD|^2 + |AB|^2$$

Rearranging we get

$$|AC|^2 - |CD|^2 = |AD|^2 = |AB|^2 - |BD|^2$$

which ends the proof.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I don't know how did you get this simple solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Writing up Pythagoras for the two sides in question, we have
$$
AE^2 + AB^2 = BE^2\\
AF^2 + AC^2 = CF^2
$$
Now, from the similarity of the three triangles $\triangle ABC, \triangle ABD, \triangle ADC$, we have $\frac{AB}{BD} = \frac{CB}{AB}$ and $\frac{AC}{CD} = \frac{CB}{AC}$. This gives
$$
AB^2 = BD \cdot CB = BD(BD + CD)\\
AC^2 = CD\cdot CB = CD(CD + BD)
$$
Inserting into the Pythagorean equations above, we get
$$
AE^2 + BD(BD + CD) = BE^2\\
AF^2 + CD(CD + BD) = CF^2
$$
By inserting $AF = BD$ and $AE = CD$ into these equations, both left-hand sides evaluates to the same value, and thus the right-hand sides must be equal as well.

Comment: Thank you for your solution based on triangle similarity :)

Answer (score 0):

let $CD=p$ and $DB=q$ then we get after the theorem of Phytagorean 
$$CF^2=b^2+q^2$$ and $$BE^2=c^2+q^2$$
it must be
$$b^2=c^2+p^2-q^2$$
this is clear when we use that
$$p^2+h^2=b^2$$ and $$q^2+h^2=c^2$$ and we get $$h=h$$
we have $$BE^2=AE^2+c^2$$ and since $$AE=CD=q$$ we get  $$BE^2=c^2+q^2$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to know how did you get $BC^2 = c^2 + q^2$